# viewDidLoad getting called before initWithFrame?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a custom init method:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect ) frame andImage:(UIImage *) image
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.view.frame = frame;
        self.imageView_.image = image;
        self.imageScrollView_.frame = self.view.frame;
        imageOriginalFrame = frame;
        zoomedImageFrame = frame;
         NSLog(@"SCREEN DIM %f AND %f", zoomedImageFrame.size.height, zoomedImageFrame.origin.y);
    }
    return self;
}
```

and here's how I present it:

```
FullSizeImageViewController * fullSize = [[FullSizeImageViewController alloc] initWithFrame:imageOriginalFrame andImage:image];
                    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(fullStoryViewController:presentModalViewController:animated:)]) {
                        [self.delegate fullStoryViewController:self presentModalViewController:fullSize animated:YES];
                    }
```

However, surprisingly my viewDidLoad is getting called before the initWithFrame. How is this possible?

I am guessing it's because I call super init? If not how do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `viewDidLoad` method is not getting called *before* your `initWithFrame:andImage:` method.  Your `viewDidLoad` method is getting called *during* your `initWithFrame:andImage:` method.

Your `initWithFrame:andImage:` method contains this line:

```
self.view.frame = frame;
```

which is shorthand for this:

```
[[self view] setFrame:frame];
```

So your method is calling the `-[UIViewController view]` method.  The `-[UIViewController view]` method is basically this:

```
- (UIView *)view {
    if (!_view) {
        [self loadView];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    return _view;
}
```

Try putting a breakpoint in your `viewDidLoad` method.  When it's hit, look at the stack trace.  You'll find `initWithFrame:andImage:` in it.

Comment: To continue the point, you should not be doing this kind of work in your init method. All of this should be in `viewDidLoad`. Your `imageView` wouldn't normally exist in your init method except that you're forcing a nib file load by referencing `view`.

Comment: so how do I then give the image and frame to the view controller? how would I pass it?

Comment: You could store it in an instance variable to use later during `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: so I just do fullSize.instanceVariable before presenting it?